# toaster js success showing background color white

Tags: javascript, jquery, notifications, toastr

toaster js for notification working properly but the background color for all the types is showing white color.

**My header is like this**

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/libs/toastr/toastr.min.css') }}">

    <!-- Bootstrap Css -->
    <link href="{{ asset('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" id="bootstrap-style" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Icons Css -->
    <link href="{{ asset('assets/css/icons.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

**Footer is like this**

```
    <script src="{{ asset('assets/libs/toastr/toastr.min.js') }}"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bootstrap contains a toaster. the bootstrap toaster and toaster js are conflicting so the all toaster background becomes white.

I just rearranged the order of the toaster and bootstrap links. the issue is solved.

```
    <!-- Bootstrap Css -->
    <link href="{{ asset('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" id="bootstrap-style" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/libs/toastr/toastr.min.css') }}">
    <!-- Icons Css -->
    <link href="{{ asset('assets/css/icons.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```